# Basis of vector space and its direct sum subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V=U_1\oplus U_2$ with $\dim(U_1)=k_1$ , $\dim(U_2)=k_2$ and $B=\{b_1,...,b_n\}$ is the basis of $V$. Are there then $k_1$ vectors of B in $U_1$ and $k_2$ vectors of B in $U_2$?

According the dimension formel I can get $k_1+k_2=n$, but does this mean that there are $k_1$ vetors which are basis of $U_1$ and $k_2$ vetors which are basis of $U_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is not *the* basis of $V$, there are many. One of these can be constructed this way:

If $\{b_1,\ldots,b_{k_1}\}$ and $\{c_1,\ldots,c_{k_2}\}$ are bases of $U_1$, $U_2$, then $\{b_1,\ldots,b_{k_1},c_1,\ldots,c_{k_2}\}$ is a basis for $V$.

Indeed: From $U_1\cap U_2 = \{0\}$ and from $b_i$, $c_j$ being independent we get that the set given above is independent,

Let me give you an example: If $V=\mathbb R^2$, $U_1 = \mathbb R\times\{0\}$, $U_2=\{0\}\times\mathbb R$. Then $\{e_1\}$, $\{e_2\}$ are bases for $U_1,U_2$ and indeed $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is a base of $V$. But $\{(1,1),(1,-1)\}$ is also a base for $V$, with obviously no base vector being in one of the subspaces.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. Just consider the case of $\mathbb{R}^3$ as the direct sum of the plane $Span\langle i,j\rangle$ and a line which is not perpendicular to the plane. A basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $\{i,j,k\}$ but none of these vectors constitute a basis of your line.